# Why my RecyclerView Overlaps my tabs?

Tags: android, tabs, android-recyclerview

I have a Navdrawer and one of my fragments have two tabs and two fragments respectively, when I full my recyclerview with some cardviews this fragment overlap the tabs an them I can't change my tabs.

My Fragment
    public class TimeLineFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener{

```
ArrayList<Gol_Entradas> dataset;
ArrayList<Gol_Entradas> gol_entradas;

Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[]{
        new FragmentRifas(),
        new FragmentSubastas()
};

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

public TimeLineFragment() {
    // es necesario el constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_time_line, container, false);


    setTabs(rootView);


    //probar cambiar por el parent
    FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    for(Fragment fragment : fragments)
    {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.tabs_host_time_line,fragment).hide(fragment);
    }

    //fragmentTransaction.show(fragments[0]).commit();



    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}


@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {



}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

private void setTabs(View rootView)
{
    final FragmentTabHost mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs_host_time_line);

    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.tabs_host_time_line);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragment_rifas").setIndicator("Rifas"),
            FragmentRifas.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragment_subastas").setIndicator("Subastas"),
            FragmentSubastas.class, null);




    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(
            new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

                    int i = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();

                    /*for(Fragment fragment : fragments)
                    {
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment);
                    }

                    fragmentTransaction.show(fragments[i]);*/

                    //mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bandera_hond);
                    Log.d("Hola como le va ",mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getBackground().toString());

                    Log.i("Esta haciendo click en", "------" + i);

                    if (i == 0) {
                        //mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                        Log.i("Inside onClick tab 0", "onClick tab");

                    }
                    else if (i ==1) {
                        //mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
                        Log.i("Inside onClick tab 1", "onClick tab");
                    }

                }
            }
    );

}
```

Fragment child

```
public class FragmentRifas extends Fragment{

private String url_ws_rifas = "http://192.168.0.3/prueba_json/json.php";
ArrayList<Rifa> rifas ;

//variable que se enviara al server
//private Map<String,String> params ;

//cupones al aire
private Integer num_cupones_al_aire = 0;


public FragmentRifas () {
    // es necesario el constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rifas, container, false);

    //inicializamos el array de rifas entradas
    rifas = new ArrayList<Rifa>();

    //para obtener los datos del ws
    getJsonWSRifas(rootView);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}


public void getJsonWSRifas(View v)
{
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    Rifa rifa = new Rifa();

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_ws_rifas, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE ", response);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                fillRifasArray(jsonArray);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("ERROR ", error.getCause().toString());
        }
    }){
        //estos valores se mandan al server por post
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap< String, String>();
            params.put("accion","0");
            params.put("COD_PAIS","0");
            params.put("codigoTipoEntrada","0");
            params.put("numeroCuponesAlAire","0");
            return params;
        }
    };


    queue.add(sr);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerRifas);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterRifas(rifas,R.layout.row_rifa));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

}

private void fillRifasArray(JSONArray array)
{
    int length = array.length();
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++ )
    {
        try {

            //variables que se obtendran y que se insertaran en el arreglo
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)array.get(i);
            Rifa rifa = new Rifa();


            Log.d("Parametro:",rifa.getEncabezado() );

            rifas.add(rifa);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

My TimeLine Layout

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tabs_host_time_line"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.goconsultores.goloyalty.activities.TimeLineFragment"
>
   <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

My Fragment Rifas

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.goconsultores.goloyalty.fragments.FragmentRifas">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:elevation="-10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerRifas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

If I put inside of FragmentRifas another control, this control also overlap my tabs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't Know Why , somebody help my, please.

Comment: I resolve the problem